# print a list and group it by a certain mapping

Tags: python

Hi heres an example of what i am trying to do

lets say there is an ordered list of words

```
list = ["Ack","Ashley","book","channel","Charlie","David","Eli,"George""Zebra"]
```

how can i print this so that

1. if there is one variable it will print without brackets or
   qutations
2. if there is more then one it will group with a bracket them based on a
   dictionary for example

> dictmap = {1: ["a", "A", "b", "B",  "c", "C"],  2:["d", "D",  "e",
>   "E",  "f", "F"],..

so all the words starting with letters that are mapped from 1: will be grouped in a bracket and so forth

so the desired output of the above list would simply be

```
[Ack,Ashely,book,channel,Charlie] [David,Eli] George Zebra
```

Comment: I don't know what to try

Comment: can you be more clear about the grouping you want? I can't see the connection between the `list` and `dictmap`

Comment: Are you grouping by the first letter? I think your dictmap is useless, you need the letters as keys.eg `{v:k for k,v in dictmap.items() for v in v}`. Then use itertools.groupby

Comment: @xvatar is it more clear? i just want to group them based on the key it its mapped from in the dictionary

Comment: oh and don't name your variables the same as builtins. `list(g)` in my answer won't work if you have shadowed `list` with a local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work

```
from itertools import groupby
L = ["Ack","Ashley","book","channel","Charlie","David","Eli","George","Zebra"]
D ={v:k for k,v in dictmap.items() for v in v}
groups = itertools.groupby(L, key=lambda x:D.get(x[0]))

for k,g in groups:
    g=list(g)
    if len(g)>1:
        print g,
    else:
        print g[0],
```

Comment: thanks so to print this on the same line, i would switch print with sys.stdout.write ?

Comment: @pyCthon, sure, or just add a comma to the end of the print statment. I'll add them to my answer

Answer (score 1):

If the original list is sorted by the same key your doing the grouping over, this should be a straightforward application of `itertools.groupby`.

Here's an untested example:

```
lst = [ ...here's the list of strings... ]

def grouping_key(elem) :
    for i, first_letters in dictmap.iteritems() :
         if elem[0] in first_letters :
             return i
    return None

for group_key, group_elems in itertools.groupby(lst, key=grouping_key) :
    group_elems = list(group_elems)
    if len(group_elems) == 1 :
        print group_elems[0]
    else :
        print group_elems
```